# Error using Max and Min based on Avg to determine lowest average cost and highest average cost (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, max, average, min

I have determined the average subject cost as per the following:

```
FROM BOOK
JOIN
(SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT,
Avg(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST
FROM BOOK
GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT) AS SUB USING (BOOK_SUBJECT)
ORDER BY BOOK_TITLE;
```

However, I now need to display the lowest average cost of books within a subject and the highest average cost of books within a subject.  I know I need to use MIN and MAX but not sure of the syntax now that I have to base it on the AVG.

Here's my attempt......

```
SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT
FROM BOOK
WHERE BOOK_COST =
(SELECT MIN(AVGCOST)
FROM BOOK)
ORDER BY BOOK_SUBJECT;

SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT
FROM BOOK
WHERE BOOK_COST =
(SELECT MAX(AVGCOST)
FROM BOOK)
ORDER BY BOOK_SUBJECT;
```

This creates a SQL error: unknown column "AVGCOST" in field list.  How do I get around this? I understand that its looking for an attribute and can't find it, so what needs to be added to the code so that MySQL will calculate the min and max of the avg?  Many thanks to those who respond, your feedback has been fabulous.

Comment: Could you clarify; if there are 3 books within the same subject and they cost £5, £10 and £15 the average is £10 ... there is no MIN(AVERAGE) and MAX(AVERAGE); Perhaps you could include a simple example of your BOOK table and an example of what you are trying to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOK
JOIN
(
   SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT,
   AVG(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST,
   MIN(BOOK_COST) AS MINCOST,
   MAX(BOOK_COST) AS MAXCOST
   FROM BOOK
   GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
) AS SUB USING (BOOK_SUBJECT)
ORDER BY BOOK_TITLE;
```

Based on

```
BOOK_SUBJECT BOOK_TITLE BOOK_COST
------------ ---------- ---------------------
MATHS        Book 1     15.99
MATHS        Book 2     14.99
MATHS        Book 3     13.99
ENGLISH      Book A     10.99
ENGLISH      Book B     9.99
```

Returns

```
BOOK_SUBJECT BOOK_TITLE BOOK_COST AVGCOST MINCOST MAXCOST
------------ ---------- --------- ------- ------- -------
MATHS        Book 1     15.99     14.99   13.99   15.99
MATHS        Book 2     14.99     14.99   13.99   15.99
MATHS        Book 3     13.99     14.99   13.99   15.99
ENGLISH      Book A     10.99     10.49   9.99    10.99
ENGLISH      Book B     9.99      10.49   9.99    10.99
```

To pull just the MIN/MAX average costs (rounded to 2 decimal)

```
SELECT 
  ROUND(MIN(MM.AVGCOST), 2) AS MINAVG, 
  ROUND(MAX(MM.AVGCOST), 2) AS MAXAVG
FROM
(
   SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT, 
   AVG(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST
   FROM BOOK
   GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
) MM
```

Will return

```
MINAVG    MAXAVG
------    ------
10.49     14.99
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean.  Here's the whole code:                                                                                            
<p>                                                                                                             
`SELECT`   
`BOOK_SUBJECT,`  
`Round(AVGCOST, 2) AS "Average Subject Cost"`  
`FROM BOOK`  <p>
 <p> 
`JOIN`  
`(SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT,`  
`Avg(BOOK_COST) AS AVGCOST`  
`FROM BOOK`  
`GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT) AS SUB USING (BOOK_SUBJECT)`  
`ORDER BY BOOK_TITLE; `<p>

Comment: The first lot of code is to determine the average cost for all the subjects.  When I run the code I get the following results:  Middleware = 89.95, Cloud = 72.45, Database = 84.95 and Programming = 66.62.  So the followup code is to select the lowest average of 66.62 and the highest average of 89.95.  I hppe this makes sense.

Comment: @ppines that makes sense; I have updated my original response with an addition that achieves this

Comment: thanks for the followup. Unfortunately the second part is causing an error:  “Every derived table must have its own alias”.  I find it strange since it clearly states MIN(AVGCOST) AS MINAVG, MAX(AVGCOST) AS MAXAVG.  Is this because it can't find these attributes in the updated table?

Comment: @ppines - I posted the code with the BOOK table written as \@BOOK, which I have just changed. Can you check that you don't have \@BOOK in your code?

Comment: yes I did amend the code as per your update and it's giving me the error.  I am using MySQL Workbench.  Would this make a difference?

Comment: Using SQL Workbench is fine. Do you have the "MM" on the end?

Comment: no!  Thanks, didn't realise I had left it off....  How do I round the result to 2 decimal places?  I have tried to amend the second part but getting a syntax error.

Comment: SELECT ROUND(MIN(MM.AVGCOST),2) AS MINAVG, ROUND(MAX(MM.AVGCOST),2) AS MAXAVG should do it

Comment: Thank you @Sean.  You are worth your weight in gold!  I voted up but it's not registering as my reputation is too low.  I appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me out.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for marking my answer as correct.